# Cannot access elements in ko foreach content

Tags: python, html, selenium, knockout.js

While building a python script using selenium, I've run into an issue interacting with a certain part of the site.  By dumping the element:attribute list from the Selenium object (chrome driver), I can see that everything located in 'ko foreach' section is not there.

```
<oc-drawer-panel id="rightDrawerPanel" right-drawer="" force-narrow="" disable-edge-swipe="" disable-swipe="" drawer-toggle-attribute="oc-drawer-toggle-right" drawer-width="90%" narrow="" selected="main" style="touch-action: auto;">

                        <div id="mainContent">
                            <iron-pages id="workspacePages" data-bind="attr: {selected: selectedWorkspaceIndex}" class="oc-pages-content" attr-for-selected="index" selected="1">
                                <!-- ko ocForEach: workspaces -->
                                <div data-oc-foreach-node="" data-bind="attr: {index: $index()}" index="0" class="">
                                    <oc-workspace-tab-control data-oc-foreach-ignore-children="" data-oc-foreach-node="" selected-tab="0" id="workspaceTabControl" data-bind="ocPropertyChanged:{viewModel: $data}"></oc-workspace-tab-control>
                                </div>

                                <div data-oc-foreach-node="" data-bind="attr: {index: $index()}" index="1" class="iron-selected">
                                    <oc-workspace-tab-control data-oc-foreach-ignore-children="" data-oc-foreach-node="" selected-tab="0" id="workspaceTabControl" data-bind="ocPropertyChanged:{viewModel: $data}"></oc-workspace-tab-control>
                                </div>

                                <div data-oc-foreach-node="" data-bind="attr: {index: $index()}" index="2">
                                    <oc-workspace-tab-control data-oc-foreach-ignore-children="" data-oc-foreach-node="" selected-tab="0" id="workspaceTabControl" data-bind="ocPropertyChanged:{viewModel: $data}"></oc-workspace-tab-control>
                                </div>

                                <div data-oc-foreach-node="" data-bind="attr: {index: $index()}" index="3">
                                    <oc-workspace-tab-control data-oc-foreach-ignore-children="" data-oc-foreach-node="" selected-tab="0" id="workspaceTabControl" data-bind="ocPropertyChanged:{viewModel: $data}"></oc-workspace-tab-control>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </iron-pages>
                        </div>
```

If I right click my target in the Chrome Inspector, copy JS Path, then paste in console I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
at <anonymous>:1:284 (anonymous) @ VM11437:1
```

I've tried in Firefox as well.  If I click "Use in console" I can successfully interact with the element var using js methods, but when I attempt to resolve the DOM path I get undefined:

```
function getDomPath(el) {
  var stack = [];
  while ( el.parentNode != null ) {
    console.log(el.nodeName);
    var sibCount = 0;
    var sibIndex = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
      var sib = el.parentNode.childNodes[i];
      if ( sib.nodeName == el.nodeName ) {
        if ( sib === el ) {
          sibIndex = sibCount;
        }
        sibCount++;
      }
    }
    if ( el.hasAttribute('id') && el.id != '' ) {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '#' + el.id);
    } else if ( sibCount > 1 ) {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ':eq(' + sibIndex + ')');
    } else {
      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    }
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return stack.slice(1); // removes the html element
}


var path = getDomPath(temp1);
console.log(path.join(' > '));

PAPER-BUTTON debugger eval code:4:13
DIV debugger eval code:4:13
paper-button#btn debugger eval code:30:9
undefined
```

If I the js path in the firefox console I get this error:

```
document.querySelector("#frameParent > oc-frame > div > oc-dynamic-control-container > oc-workspaces-tabs").shadowRoot.querySelector("#workspaceTabControl").shadowRoot.querySelector("#tabPageContent > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > oc-dynamic-control-container > oc-search-criteria").shadowRoot.querySelector("#commandBarContainer > oc-command-bar > oc-command-bar-item:nth-child(3)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#btn")
TypeError: document.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.querySelector(...) is null
```

Any ideas on how to access these elements?